# Why does $f(x + \Delta x)=f(x)$

Tags: calculus

I'm just starting calculus, and was wondering if it is correct that $$f(x + \Delta x)=f(x)$$ and if so why? I'm looking for an intuitive understanding of how the variables relate.

Comment: Depends on what $\Delta x$ is.

Comment: In general no, you should define $\Delta x$. The equality is true, for example, if $f$ is a periodic function with period $\Delta x$. I suppose you are talking about the case in which $\Delta x \to 0$.

Comment: It depends on $f,x$, and $\Delta x$, but usually this is not true.

Comment: We need more context. It's false in general.

Comment: $\Delta x$ is just another quantity, the intent is that it is a small modification of $x$. In general you will not have equality above just as you generally don't have $f(x)=f(y)$ for different $x,y$.

Comment: It can if $f$ is periodic and $\Delta x$ is the period of $f$.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous and $\Delta x$ is very small then $f(x+\Delta x) \approx f(x)$ and the agreement becomes better and better the smaller $\Delta x$ is (this is basically the definition of continuity). However strickt equality is seldom the case.

Comment: In some sense you might say Calculus is all about the _difference_ between $f(x+\Delta x)$ and $f(x)$. Why would you think they should be equal? Did you mean to write something different? This question definitely needs a lot more detail to help us understand what you're thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in general $f(x+\Delta x) \neq f(x)$. Though the quantity $f(x+\Delta x)$ can be estimated in terms of $f(x)$.

For differentiable functions, the quantity $f(x + \Delta x)$ can be estimated by using a linearization of the function at $x$. This is a little bit better than saying that $f(x + \Delta x)$ is about the same as $f(x)$, which is true for small $x$. Using the linearization to estimate a function at $f(x+\Delta x)$ provides a slightly better accuracy.

This is the difference between saying $f(x+\Delta x) \approx f(x)$ (constant estimation) vs $f(x+\Delta x) \approx f(x) + f'(x) \Delta x$ (linear estimation).

---

For instance we can estimate the square root of $17$ by using the linearization of $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ at $x=16$. Note that $f(16)=4$ and $f'(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ so that $f'(16) = \frac{1}{8}$. Thus $f(17) = f(16 + 1) \approx f(16) + \frac18 \cdot 1 = 4.125$.

---

When a function is differentiable we have, $$f(x+\Delta x) = f(x) + \xi \cdot \Delta x + \text{junk}$$ for some $\xi$ and where the junk term becomes very small (read: negligible) when $\Delta x$ is small. In fact if we write $\text{junk} = o(\Delta x)$ we have $o(\Delta x)/\Delta x \to 0$ as $\Delta x \to 0$.

In fact, if we write $$f'(x) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x+\Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{(f(x) + \xi \Delta x + \text{junk}) - f(x)}{\Delta x} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \left( \xi + \frac{o(\Delta x)}{\Delta x}\right) = \xi.$$

Thus $f'(x) = \xi$ and $f(x+\Delta x) = f(x) + f'(x) \Delta x + o(\Delta x).$

---

Example:

Consider $f(x) = x^2 + 2x + 1$. Then $f(x + \Delta x) = (x+\Delta x)^2 + 2(x + \Delta x) + 1$.

Using the binomial theorem (or FOIL) we have $$f(x + \Delta x) = x^2 + 2\Delta x \cdot x + \Delta x^2 + 2x + 2\Delta x + 1.$$

Collecting terms we find:

$$f(x + \Delta x) = (x^2 + 2x + 1) + (2 x + 2)\Delta x + \Delta x^2.$$

Recall that $f'(x) = 2x + 2$. Thus we have

$$f(x + \Delta x) = f(x) + f'(x) \Delta x + \Delta x^2.$$

Now notice that our junk term is $o(\Delta x) = \Delta x^2$, and $o(\Delta x)/\Delta x = \Delta x \to 0$ as $\Delta x \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. I think you meant to ask if $$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} f(x+\Delta x) = f(x).$$

The equation above is the **definition** of *continuity at $x$*. This means that if the above equation is true for some value of $x$, then the function is continuous at $x$.

For example, $f(x) = 3x+2$. This is a line (which is continuous). Notice $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} f(x+\Delta x) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} 3x+3\Delta x + 2 = 3x +2$.

However, for the function $$f(x) = \begin{cases}1 & \text{ if } x \geq 0\\0&\text{ if } x< 0\end{cases},$$ it is not true that $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} f(0+\Delta x) = f(0)$ (because the limit from the left is 0, not 1).